# What site can I find a dataset containing parameters related to the heart condition that I could use to train a machine learning model?

Tags: python, azure, tensorflow, kaggle, automl

I want to train a machine learning model on anomaly detection and predictive analysis but am not so sure where I could get a reliable dataset that would produce close to a perfect model.

So far I have only found not so reliable datasets that cannot be trusted
Therefore I have decided not to commit on working with them

Comment: Recommendation questions are expressly off-topic. Also, none of your tags apply to anything in your question.

Answer (score -1):

Kaggle has some good datasets for heart condition prediction. Have a look [here](https://www.kaggle.com/search?q=heart+datasetFileTypes%3Acsv+datasetFileTypes%3Atxt). 
These are some of the other ones I found: [UCI](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/dataset/45/heart+disease), [IEEE DataPort](https://ieee-dataport.org/open-access/heart-disease-dataset-comprehensive), [US Data.GOV](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/?q=heart&sort=views_recent+desc&ext_location=&ext_bbox=&ext_prev_extent=)

Comment: Recommendation questions are expressly off-topic. Also, this isn't a programming question. Please don't post answers to off-topic questions.